# mysqli show "no results found"

Tags: php, mysqli

I would like to show "no results found" if there are no rows matching the query. 
i I have tried:

```
if(!$result) {echo"no results found";}
```

and

```
if($stmt->num_rows < 1) {echo"no results found"}
```

but none of them work. What is a correct procedure?

```
 $stmt = $mydb->prepare("SELECT * FROM messages where from_user = ? and deleted = 'yes' or to_user  = ? and deleted = 'yes'");
 $stmt->bind_param('ss', $username->username, $username->username);
 $stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
echo $row['message'];}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this
    `if($result->num_rows < 1)`
Instead of
    `if($stmt->num_rows < 1)`

You get num_rows at result object

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php if($stmt->num_rows != 0) {
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
echo $row['message'];}
} else {echo"no results found";} ?>
```

Comment: What's the essential difference between `num_rows != 0` and `num_rows < 1` that makes you believe first one is better?

Comment: you can use anyone of them,your motto is to disply "no result found" right?

Comment: if you can use anyone of them, what's the value of your answer?

Comment: @chiragode yeah but it shows "no results found" even though there are results

Comment: @YourCommonSense ..yaa i know.!! :-)